# Select rows for a date range applied on one datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below table, how to get what **statuses** the user was in between '2016-12-12 00:00:00.0' and '2017-02-20 23:59:59.999'. The result should be **emailVerified** and **active**

```
userid  status          actionDateTime
113     emailPending    2016-11-24 11:59:26.427
113     emailVerified   2016-12-10 17:21:15.240
113     Active          2017-02-07 13:24:01.330
```

Comment: Paste the table as text, not XML.

Comment: The result will be return only `Active` if date was between `2016-12-12 00:00:00.0` and `2017-02-20 23:59:59.999`.  `emailVerified` is for `2016-12-10 ` !!

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader  On 2016-12-12 his status was emailVerified, I want that also.

Comment: @itsraja, Edit your question by applying the `2016-12-12 his status was emailVerified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the **biggest smaller** date and the **smallest bigger** date.

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(userid INT,[status] NVARCHAR(100),actionDateTime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (113,'emailPending',{ts'2016-11-24 11:59:26.427'})
,(113,'emailVerified',{ts'2016-12-10 17:21:15.240'})
,(113,'Active',{ts'2017-02-07 13:24:01.330'});

DECLARE @From DATETIME={ts'2016-12-12 00:00:00'};
DECLARE @To   DATETIME={ts'2017-02-20 23:59:59'};

SELECT * FROM @tbl AS t
WHERE t.actionDateTime >= ISNULL((SELECT MAX(x.actionDateTime) FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.actionDateTime<@From),{d'2000-01-01'})
  AND t.actionDateTime <= ISNULL((SELECT MIN(x.actionDateTime) FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.actionDateTime>@To),{d'9999-01-01'});
```

The result

```
userid  status           actionDateTime
113     emailVerified   2016-12-10 17:21:15.240
113     Active          2017-02-07 13:24:01.330
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BETWEEN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT status FROM table WHERE actionDateTime BETWEEN '2016-12-12 00:00:00.0' AND '2017-02-20 23:59:59.999'
```

Or by User:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status FROM (
SELECT userid, status
FROM table 
WHERE actionDateTime BETWEEN '2016-12-12 00:00:00.0' AND '2017-02-20 23:59:59.999'
)
```

Based on your comment this might be what you need:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    userid
    ,status
    ,actionDateTime as DateFrom
    ,ISNULL(LEAD(actionDateTime, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY actionDateTime), '9999-12-31') as DateTo
FROM table
)
SELECT DISTINCT userid, status
FROM CTE
WHERE DateTo BETWEEN '2016-12-12 00:00:00.0' AND '2017-02-20 23:59:59.999'
```

Comment: it will return only active

Comment: @itsraja Your data for `emailVerified` has `2016-12-10`, so this result should be fine... Shouldn't it?

Comment: @Shnugo No, Here I have only one column to update the status change. On 2016-12-12 he was emailVerified and on 2017-02-20 he was active. I want both. If I have From and To dates for each status then it will work. But here I got to consider previously update date for status for the given fromDate.

Comment: The code just builds a range for each status by getting the next change date. Then you have a DateFrom and DateTo and can filter on that.

Comment: `between` can be misleading. You might want to read this: [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) and this: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT status
FROM table
WHERE actionDateTime BETWEEN '2016-12-12 00:00:00.0' AND '2017-02-20 23:59:59.999'
```

Comment: `between` can be misleading. You might want to read this: [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) and this: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)